# SQL Server - Date between 2 dates from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue where I keep getting null (or 0, if I use the isnull function) in my case statement below. I am trying to say that when ord_due_date from one table is between two dates from another table, to return a value. I am not certain why it continues to return null values. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
+cast(isnull(CASE
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date<=prd01_end_date 
    THEN '01 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd01_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd02_end_date
    THEN '02 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd02_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd03_end_date
    THEN '03 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd03_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd04_end_date
    THEN '04 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd04_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd05_end_date
    THEN '05 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd05_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd06_end_date
    THEN '06 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd06_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd07_end_date
    THEN '07 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd07_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd08_end_date
    THEN '08 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd08_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd09_end_date
    THEN '09 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd09_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd10_end_date
    THEN '10 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd10_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd11_end_date
    THEN '11 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd11_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd12_end_date
    THEN '12 '+year(ord_due_date)
WHEN year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr and ord_due_date>prd12_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd13_end_date
    THEN '13 '+year(ord_due_date)
END,0) as varchar(40))+'    '+
```

EDIT: To add data from those columns

Ord_Due_Date (date)

[image]

Cal_Yr (numeric) and Prd_End_Date (date)

[image]

Comment: Your logic is probably wrong, no WHEN matches and then there's a NULL returned. Btw, instead of `ISNULL` you can simply add an `ELSE`. Can you show some data and the data types of those columns?

Comment: The else is a good suggestion, thanks. As you can see from the data, there are dates that fall between prd_end_dates. Still returning nulls, though

Comment: Your example data should match the `ord_due_date>prd10_end_date AND ord_due_date<=prd11_end_date`, strange. Btw, your CASE is way to complicated, both `year(ord_due_date)=cal_yr` and `ord_due_date>prd.._end_date` can be removed without changing the result.

Comment: Did you cuttoff the prd13_end_date in the pic? Your query attempts to get that column for last days of the year.  And, actually I don't think you need that column anyway... if it's it's the last part of the year, just check where the date is greater than PRD12_END_DATE.  Oh.. actually I also see PRD05_END_DATE to PRD09_ENDDATE missing as well.  Just checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to concatenate and cast each piece of my THEN statement as varchar for it to work. It didn’t like me using a numeric and combining it with a date.

THEN concat(cast(‘11’ as varchar(10)),’ ‘,cast(year(ord_due_date) as varchar(10)))

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you must use the isnull to the date field directly rather than the whole query

for example

case
WHEN year(isnull(ord_due_date,0))=isnull(cal_yr,0) and isnull(ord_due_date,0)<=isnull(prd01_end_date,0) THEN '01 '+year(**isnull(ord_due_date,0)**)